# Keeping MVC clean with a programmatically written view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller

i tired to write my subview programmatically, cause i wanted to have nice rounded Button with Images. So i wrote myView.h and myView.m with an init method wich looks sth like this:

```
- (id)init 
{
  if (self = [super init]){
    redBlack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redB.png"];
    redWhite = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redW.png"];

    redButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    redButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 30.0, 130.0, 130.0);
    [redButton setBackgroundImage:redBlack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [redButton setBackgroundImage:redWhite forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [redButton addTarget:self action:@selector(controller.colorButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [redButton setTag:0];
    [self.view addSubview:redButton];
.....
```

The Problem is, that colorButtonPressed is a Method, which is written in my ControllerView-Singleton.
I don't know if i am doing this right, but actually i wanted to keep the MVC as clean as possible. Is it a common way to do it like this and if so, the compiler doesnt let me write controller.colorButtonPressed: in @selector ?!?
Or should i specify the programmatically written view also in my controller class?
Hopefully these questions dont sound too stupid!?
And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 [redButton addTarget:self action:@selector(controller.colorButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

it should be:

```
 [redButton addTarget:controller action:@selector(colorButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: But the method colorButtonPressed: is not declared in the same class ?!

Comment: But the target is where the action is sent to. I thought you had `colorButtonPressed:` in `controller`?

Comment: yes i do, oh so the action got recognized, although it is not written in this class. Do i have to declare The Method as an IBAction, then? I thought i dont have to do that, if i am writing the view by myself.

Comment: The selector is just the method name. It doesn't say what class the method belongs to. When the button is pressed it "sends" the selector (the action) to the target. IBAction is exactly the same as void, it is there to tell Interface Builder that the method should be displayed in IB's UI.

Comment: To put it another way, the target  (the `addTarget` parameter) is where the `action` is written. So when you press the button it will effectively do this code: `[controller colorButtonPressed:self];` because you put `controller` in the `addTarget` param, and you put the selector in the `action` param

Answer (score 0):

the target needs to be the class the method is defined in.

If the target is set to "self" then the method should be in the same class. Seems by your code that the method is in controller which means that target should be "controller" and selector should be @selector(colorButtonPressed:)